# Keeps installing Firebase 2.5.1 instead of the latest version with Cocoapods installation

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Basically I did as instructed by the firebase.google.com website on how to set up. Everything sets up alright, until I tried to FIRApp.Configure() in the App Delegate. Received an error. Reinstall the Cocoapods to realize the version is 2.5.1 which I don't believe is the latest version. So how do I get the latest version is my question?

Note: Using Swift, pod search only shows 2.5.1 as latest.

Pod file:

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'OptionMeFood' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for OptionMeFood
  pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Comment: Can you post the text in your pod file please?

Comment: Yes, it has been uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put this in your Podfile without a version number, It should then load the latest version (3.2):

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_the_sdk

> This will add the latest version of the Firebase pod, which include the /Core subspec. This provides Firebase Analytics. A list of currently available pods and subspecs is provided below. These are linked in feature specific setup guides as well.

Comment: Yes I did it without the number as you said. Also when I pod search it shows that the latest version is 2.5.1 if that is any help. I am also using Swift btw.

Comment: glad to of helped :)